# How to reduce load time of curl and parse html

Tags: php, parsing, curl

i need to reduce load time of my script. It is curl and simple parse dom.
This is my script, i need help :(
It lasts about 2 minutes, i need to parse many different pages!

```
    require_once ("simple_html_dom.php");

    function curl ($page){
        ob_start();
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "URL");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "POSTFIELDS");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        ob_end_clean();
        return $result;
    }
    $start = microtime(true);
    set_time_limit(0);
    $text = "here text of last page";

    $i = 0;
    while(strpos(str_get_html(curl($i)), $text) == null){
        $html = str_get_html(curl($i));
        foreach($html->find('div#box-container-inner div.box') as $e){
PRINT etc... only for test
        }
        echo "parsata la pagina ".($i+1)."<br>";
        $i++;
    }
    $time_elapsed_secs = (microtime(true) - $start)/60;
    echo $time_elapsed_secs;
```

Comment: So, a few observations. You appear to be running CURL twice in each loop (once to evaluate the while-loop condition, once to set `$html`) and converting the resulting string into an object for each loop. You could try `while(strpos(($html = str_get_html(curl($i))), $text) === null) {` and removing the `$html = str_get_html(curl($i));` line.

Comment: How many pages are getting read when the script runs, out of curiousity?

Comment: @ChrisForrence if i write while(strpos(($html = str_get_html(curl($i))), $text) === null) { without first line of while, i get only echo $time_elapsed_secs; :(
i've to parse about 17/18 page. it's a dynamic content.

Comment: That's actually more because [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns false instead of null if the string doesn't exist (mea culpa); instead of `=== null`, use `=== false`

Comment: @ChrisForrence now it's faster than before. Now i've to optimize mysql insert and control.. can you advice to me something my friend?

$query ="SELECT count(*) as total FROM db WHERE id=".$id;
$ris = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die (mysql_error());
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($ris);
$presence = $data['total'];

if ($presence == 1){
already present
}
else{
$newquery = "INSERT INTO cristiano (id, titolo, link) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$tolgoapostrofi."', '".$link."')";
  $result=mysql_query($newquery,$connessione); 
  if($result==0) die(mysql_error()."errore database controlla");
}
}

Comment: I'd advise opening a new question for that; it's a different question altogether, and asking multiple disparate questions as a single question can get that question closed as too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be running CURL twice in each loop (once to evaluate the while-loop condition, once to set $html) and converting the resulting string into an object for each loop. That's four potentially-intensive processes each time you loop that you can knock down to two per loop.

Instead, you can assign the $html variable to the result of `str_get_html(curl($i))` while within the while-loop evaluation:

```
while(strpos(($html = str_get_html(curl($i))), $text) === false) {
//    $html = str_get_html(curl($i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add  curl timeout as parameter set to 60 seconds or your choice.

**curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);**